# TDD. Calendar. Как писать тесты на методы работающие с датой, если там используется и текущая?

Tags: java, test-driven-development, calendar

У меня есть метод:

```
public int checkQuality() {
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    long differenceOne = this.expireDate.getTimeInMillis() - this.createDate.getTimeInMillis();
    long differenceTwo = currentDate.getTimeInMillis() - this.createDate.getTimeInMillis();
    return (int) (((float) differenceTwo / differenceOne) * 100);
}
```

Он проверяет в процентах на сколько вышел срок годности товара в процентах, и возвращает `int` этих процентов.

Мне нужно его протестировать и первый тест выглядит так:

```
@Test
public void whenThen() {
    Calendar createDate = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 11, 16);
    Calendar expireDate = new GregorianCalendar(2017, 11, 31);
    Product food = new Food(createDate, expireDate);
    ControlQuality control = new ControlQuality();
    control.uploadInRepo(food);
    assertThat(food, is(control.getRepo().get(0).getProducts().get(0)));
}
```

Совершенно очевидно что через пару дней он уже работать не будет.
Можно конечно при создании объектов `Calendar` оттолкнуться от текущей даты, но мне кажется это какой-то костыль...
Как мне сделать что-бы это работало всегда без палок, лома, и прочей подручной утвари?

Comment: как бы это смешно не звучало, сделать CalendarProvider и передавать его внутрь

Comment: А как это сделать что-то я не пойму...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Совершенно очевидно что через пару дней он уже работать не будет.

Я бы сказал, что совершенно неочевидно. Потому что непонятно, какое отношения эта строка:

```
assertThat(food, is(control.getRepo().get(0).getProducts().get(0)));
```

имеет к приведенному вами методу `checkQuality()` (но подозреваю, что ваш репозиторий просто не возвращает протухшие товары).

Если вы хотите проверять "прогресс качества", то пишите тесты сперва на `checkQuality()`, а потом уже добавляйте более высокоуровневые тесты (если они вообще нужны).

Что касается даты. Одно из главных положений юнит-тестирования заключается в том, что мы должны/хотим проверять только код того юнита, который мы тестируем. Это значит, что мы не должны/не хотим проверять любой другой сторонний код. Особенно если этот код требует предварительной сложной настройки (например, обращение к БД) или "капризен" (текущая дата). Что делается с кодом, который мы не хотим тестировать? Он выделяется в зависимости для текущего юнита (читай, класса/метода) и мокается в тесте (т.е. мы сами задаем ему нужное поведение).

Поэтому самый простой вариант -- передавать `Calendar currentDate` извне, так же, как и `expireDate` и `createDate`. Это может быть реализовано в лоб -- вы передаете непосредственно `Calendar`, так и обходным путем -- с передачей некоторого провайдера, который будет возвращать календарь. В тесте же поведение этой зависимости вы будете определять сами, добиваясь желаемого результата.

Да, и еще один совет: даты в тестах не должны содержать абсолютные значения! Значения должны быть только относительные, например, `сегодня - 7 дней`, `сегодня + 2 дня`. Только так тесты, связанные с датами, будут работать всегда, а не только сегодня или завтра.

Comment: >>>Поэтому самый простой вариант -- передавать Calendar currentDate извне<<< Что вы имеете в виду под "из вне" если речь идет об инициализации прямо во время теста то здесь так и есть. А если что-то другое то я вас не понял, поясните пожалуйста чуть по подробнее.

Comment: @Павел в самом простом случае -- вот так: `checkQuality(Calendar currentDate)`. В более сложном так: `new Food(expireDate, createDate, new CalendarProvider())`, а затем внутри `checkQuality` получать: `Calendar currentDate = calendarProvider.GetCalendar();`.